# How to install, fglrx on (K)ubuntu 15.04 ? Starting version 219 AMD R9 290x

Tags: drivers, upgrade, 15.04, fglrx

i have upgraded my Ubuntu 14.10 to Kubuntu 15.04 and as i thought the graphics driver would mess up.

I am looking for a step-by-step tutorial how to install fglrx on Kubuntu 15.04.

On 14.04 i had absolutely NO problems.
I just downloaded the driver from the AMD Homepage and compiled it and it ran perfectly.(...until i installed Wine)

I want to install this here . [Ubuntu 15.04 Catalyst 15.3 Beta](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-15.04-15.3-Beta)
by installing it via sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates

```
edd@edd-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
[sudo] password for edd: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fglrx-amdcccle-updates fglrx-updates-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fglrx-amdcccle-updates fglrx-updates fglrx-updates-core
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/115 MB of archives.
After this operation, 480 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-updates-core.
(Reading database ... 202691 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../fglrx-updates-core_2%3a15.200-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fglrx-updates-core (2:15.200-0ubuntu4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-updates.
Preparing to unpack .../fglrx-updates_2%3a15.200-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fglrx-updates (2:15.200-0ubuntu4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-amdcccle-updates.
Preparing to unpack .../fglrx-amdcccle-updates_2%3a15.200-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fglrx-amdcccle-updates (2:15.200-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for systemd (219-7ubuntu5) ...
Setting up fglrx-updates-core (2:15.200-0ubuntu4) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx-core/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GFXCORE.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gfxcore_conf) in auto mode
Loading new fglrx-updates-core-15.200 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.16.0-38-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up fglrx-updates (2:15.200-0ubuntu4) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
Setting up fglrx-amdcccle-updates (2:15.200-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu15) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/sdb7
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (219-7ubuntu5) ...
```

Edit:
I have installed linux-generic but still Blackscreen.
Of course i purged fglrx* before reinstalling it.

```
$edd@edd-desktop:~$ dpkg -l | grep headers

ii  linux-generic                                         3.19.0.18.17                               amd64        Complete Generic         Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-18                              3.19.0-18.18                               all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic                      3.19.0-18.18                               amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                                3.19.0.18.17                               amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers

edd@edd-desktop:~$ uname -a
Linux edd-desktop 3.19.0-18-generic #18-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 19 18:31:35 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


edd@edd-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall fglrx
[sudo] password for edd: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-core
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/115 MB of archives.
After this operation, 480 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-core.
(Reading database ... 232889 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack .../fglrx-core_2%3a15.200-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ... Unpacking fglrx-core (2:15.200-0ubuntu4) ... 
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx. 
Preparing to unpack .../fglrx_2%3a15.200-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ... 
Unpacking fglrx (2:15.200-0ubuntu4) ... 
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-amdcccle. 
Preparing to unpack .../fglrx-amdcccle_2%3a15.200-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ... Unpacking fglrx-amdcccle (2:15.200-0ubuntu4) ... 
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ... 
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot Processing triggers for systemd (219-7ubuntu5) ... 
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ... 
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ... 
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ... Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index... 
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ... 
Setting up fglrx-core (2:15.200-0ubuntu4) ... 
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx-core/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GFXCORE.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gfxcore_conf) in auto mode Loading new fglrx-core-15.200 DKMS files... First Installation: checking all kernels... 
Building only for 3.19.0-18-generic 
Building for architecture x86_64 
Building initial module for 3.19.0-18-generic Done. 
fglrx: Running module version sanity check. 
- Original module - No original module exists within this kernel - Installation - Installing to /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/updates/dkms/ depmod........ 
DKMS: install completed. update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated) Setting up fglrx (2:15.200-0ubuntu4) ... 
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken 
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode Setting up fglrx-amdcccle (2:15.200-0ubuntu4) ... Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu15) ... 
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-18-generic cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/sdb7 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ... 
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ... 
Processing triggers for systemd (219-7ubuntu5) ... 

edd@edd-desktop:~$ uname -a Linux edd-desktop 3.19.0-18-generic
```

## #18-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 19 18:31:35 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
edd@edd-desktop:~$ dpkg -l | grep headers

ii  linux-generic                                        3.19.0.18.17                               amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-18                              3.19.0-18.18                               all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.19.0
ii  linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic                      3.19.0-18.18                               amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                                3.19.0.18.17                               amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
```

Comment: That should already be in the Vivid repositories, though... is there a reason you want to install the already existing version?

Comment: I dont want the Desktop to lagg anymore. With the fglrx drivers it ran smoothly

Comment: Are linux-headers-generic installed? The kernel module does not build.

Comment: Please add output of `uname -a` and `dpkg -l | grep headers`

Comment: i edited my question and pasted the output. But i dont know how to format the text properly.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall fglrx` and replace the old output. It could change.

Comment: It looks like it is installed properly now. But you spoiled formatting so badly, I do not know how to fix it easily. Does it work now?

Comment: I rebooted and it starts with a blackscreen showing: starting Version 219 and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it by running

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

According to install log, the kernel module does not build. And also you seem to have a wrong kernel for Kubuntu 15.04. The upgrade from 14.10 is not always smooth. That must be the reason.

This must be fixed by:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

Comment: This leads to a Blackscreen boot. And "Starting Version 219" I need a real "trick" to install the latest 15.3 Beta drivers or the one that works.

Comment: That means that this beta driver is not that good for your adapter.

Comment: You can add output of this command to your question. Maybe I have same ideas.

Comment: What shall i add exactly ? Output ? Iam new to this board here. Sorry

Comment: Remove that driver from console `Ctrl+Alt+F1` by `sudo apt-get purge fglrx*`. Then reboot and try to install it again. And add terminal output of `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates` to your initial post.

Comment: sudo apt-get purge fglrx*   i can leave this out, becuase i have already purged the drivers. with this command. Shall i make a photo and add it here after i installed it ia fglrx-updates ?

Comment: No. No photos, pls. Just copy text from terminal, after you install it.

Comment: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3998/qjongnzy_jpg.ht

Comment: Uxterminal doesnt allow copy and Paste. Sorry. After purging and reinstalling  via fglrx-Updates stuck in kubuntu Boot logo

Comment: Why don't you just copy TEXT, edit your initial post and add it there, instead of uploading big photos?

Comment: It does allow. User mouse right-click or Ctrl+Shift+C.

Comment: Im not a total Idiot.  Kubuntu Terminal just Shows NO reaction to my right click.